# Get Camera's Rectangle position from CesiumJS

Tags: javascript, 3d, data-visualization, cesiumjs

I am having trouble to get Rectangle position of current Camera view.

I want to create a Rectangle or Wall on the same position as current Camera view (red rectangle). Is there any way to do this?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: What distance from the camera should this be?  Is it aligned with the first near plane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand you problem, but I think you may have luck using the the Cesium camera's computeViewRectangle function to get the approximate rectangle the camera can see.

Here is the documentation: 
https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Camera.html#computeViewRectangle

Comment: Yes, That's corrent solution. They added it few days after asking this question but thanks :).